# Player Function a nill value

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am making a little script to see if I can stop people using NoClip by checking their SteamID. DarkRP nor ULX are installed. Just using base GMOD to see if I can learn scripting for GMOD as a hobby - quite new :)

```
TABLE = TABLE or {}
TABLE.PLAYERS = {
["STEAM_0:1:89436878"] = true,
}
local plyMeta = getmetatable("player")
function plyMeta:CanNoClip()
    for id, bool in pairs(TABLE.PLAYERS) do
        if id == self:SteamID() then
            print(self:Nick() .. " can noclip")
            return true
        else
            print(self:Nick() .. " cannot noclip")
            return false
        end
    end
end
hook.Add("PlayerNoClip", "CheckPlayerCanNoClip", function(ply, state)
    ply:CanNoClip()
end)
```

The error I get in the console is...

```
attmpt to call method 'CanNoClip' (a nill value)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line:

```
 ply:CanNoClip()
```

`ply` is a `Player` object. There is no `CanNoClip` method in the `Player` class. So you're trying to call a nil value which is not allowed.

You added that function to the metatable that is shared by all strings.

```
local plyMeta = getmetatable("player")
function plyMeta:CanNoClip()
-- your code
end
```

`"player"` is a string so `getmetatable("player")` gives you the metatable of that string.